# How to use data from GraphQL in a React component in GatsbyJS

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to query for a specific category title and returning it inside a div. It gives me the following error message:

`TypeError: can't access property "node", data.edges is undefined`

This is my file:

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { H3, BodyMain } from "../styles/TextStyles"

export default function CategorySection() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query categoryQuery {
      allGraphCmsCategory(filter: { title: { eq: "CSS" } }) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            slug
            description
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ContentWrapper>
        <TextWrapper>
          <Title>Browse by Categories</Title>
          <Description>
            Use the category tags to narrow down what you are looking for.
          </Description>
        </TextWrapper>
        <CategoryWrapper>
          <Categories>{data.edges.node.title}</Categories>
        </CategoryWrapper>
      </ContentWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

const Wrapper = styled.div``

const ContentWrapper = styled.div``

const TextWrapper = styled.div``

const Title = styled(H3)``

const Description = styled(BodyMain)``

const CategoryWrapper = styled.div``

const Categories = styled.div``
```

I believe my query is right, as I'm able to see results on http://localhost:8000/___graphql

When I have tested it and see it work, I would like to map through all categories and create separate pages for each.

Can you guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Use `console.log`. @Ferran's answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It still tricks me a bit as you can see in the comments.

Comment: eh, edges is an array ... try `{data.allGraphCmsCategory.edges[0].node.title}

Comment: you should see that after `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks good, however, you need to access the nested object as your GraphQL shows, in your case, this should work:

```
export default function CategorySection() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query categoryQuery {
      allGraphCmsCategory(filter: { title: { eq: "CSS" } }) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            slug
            description
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

 console.log("your data is", data.allGraphCmsCategory.edges) // use to access to the nested data data.allGraphCmsCategory.edges[0].node.title
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ContentWrapper>
        <TextWrapper>
          <Title>Browse by Categories</Title>
          <Description>
            Use the category tags to narrow down what you are looking for.
          </Description>
        </TextWrapper>
        <CategoryWrapper>
          <Categories>{data.edges.node.title}</Categories>
        </CategoryWrapper>
      </ContentWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Note that, inside data, you first need to access `allGraphCmsCategory` and keep following the object tree. I've assumed (because of the `all` keyword in `allGraphCmsCategory`) that the result will have multiple edges nodes (array), that's why the `edges[0]`.

Alternatively, you can use the StaticVersion component:

```
    export default function CategorySection() {
       return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query categoryQuery {
          allGraphCmsCategory(filter: { title: { eq: "CSS" } }) {
            edges {
              node {
                title
                slug
                description
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={data => {
       console.log(data);
       return (
        <Wrapper>
          <ContentWrapper>
            <TextWrapper>
              <Title>Browse by Categories</Title>
              <Description>
                Use the category tags to narrow down what you are looking for.
              </Description>
            </TextWrapper>
            <CategoryWrapper>
              <Categories>{data.allGraphCmsCategory.edges[0].node.title}</Categories>
            </CategoryWrapper>
          </ContentWrapper>
        </Wrapper>
      )
      }}
    />
  )
    }
```

To make it dynamic:

```
{data.allGraphCmsCategory.edges.map(item=>{
return <Categories>{item.title}</Categories>
})}
```

Comment: I tried to implement the console.log, but I must do it wrong. It gives me this error now: "TypeError: can't access property 0, data.allGraphCmsCategory.edges.node is undefined"

Comment: I'm not sure if it has something to do with getting the data from GraphCMS. If I do a useStaticQuery with local files, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said that I've assumed some stuff but without knowing your data structure it's impossible. Change the console to `console.log(data.allGraphCmsCategory.edges)` to check the output

Comment: Yeah that make sense. It's just odd that I can use localhost:8000/___graphql with the same query and get results, but using it in useStaticQuery gives me undefined results.

Comment: Is `data` always undefined? `console.log(data)`

Comment: I seems like it, yeah. I have tried changing around a bit, but cannot get it to work.

Comment: I've added a `<StaticQuery>` component approach. It seems that some CMS does not support `useStaticQuery` hook yet (even though graphCMS seems to...). Remember to top your develop server and rerun it again in each trial

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the <StaticQuery> example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228296/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-mathias-riis-sorensen).